# change SQL limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This comes up when I try to load from an array in my Terminal:

```
Site Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "sites".* FROM "sites" WHERE "sites"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1
```

I want to change the limit from 1 so that I can show multiple things in my ERB file. 
This is how I'm trying to show them in my ERB file.

```
<% if @sites.is_a? Array %>
    <% @sites.take(8).each do |site| %>
    <!-- list to make things inline -->
    <ul class="site_tab">
        <li>
            <a href="/site/<%=site.id%>"><%=site.text%></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/delete_site?site_id=<%= site.id %>">
                <img class="delete_button" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/geomicons/32/672366-x-128.png"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
<% elsif @sites.is_a? Site %>
<% @sites.take(8).each do |site| %>
    <!-- list to make things inline -->
    <ul class="site_tab">
        <li>
            <a href="/site/<%= site.id%>"><%= site.text %></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/delete_site?site_id=<%= site.id %>">
                <img class="delete_button" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/geomicons/32/672366-x-128.png"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <%end%>
<% else %>
    <h2>No sites to display</h2>
<% end %>
```

How do I change the limit? .take hasn't worked and .limit hasnt worked

Comment: What is the your function that you used to get data in controller?

Comment: theres a new_site.erb that deals with that @dieuhd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is in your controller, not your view. You probably have something like

```
@sites = Site.find_by user_id: current_user.id
```

or

```
@sites = current_user.sites.first
```

Note in both cases `@sites` will be a single `Site`, not an array. This would produce an array though:

```
@sites = current_user.sites.limit(1)
```

Also btw in your `elsif @sites.is_a? Site`, saying `@sites.take(8).each` doesn't make sense because it's not an array.

Comment: But wouldn't I need to reference the Site class?

Comment: I ended  up getting it to work with a line of code involving the user ID and the .flatten command, but thanks again for your help even though this is a very late comment!